# Is it possible to connect Chromecast to hotel network using VPN?

Tags: windows-8, vpn, chromecast

I have searched for a way to get Chromecast to work over a hotel network (redirects to an "accept terms and agreements page" on first connect) without using an external router. I want to know if it is possible connect to a VPN and pipe / remap the internet connection from the hotel network to the Chromecast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hotel wifi will block all access until you go through that page.

Do not connect the Chromecast until this is done: Find the MAC address of your chromecast, spoof the MAC using a wifi adapter on your laptop or smartphone, go to the "accept terms and agreements page". Go to a website to make sure the internet works. Now change your MAC address back. Chromecast should now have it's MAC added to the "allow" list on the hotel network.

Some networks have expiring authentication so you may need to repeat this process.